# Is a DFS Cypher Query possible?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My database contains about 300k nodes and 350k relationships.

My current query is:

`start n=node(3) match p=(n)-[r:move*1..2]->(m) where all(r2 in relationships(p) where r2.GameID = STR(id(n))) return m;`

The nodes touched in this query are all of the same kind, they are different positions in a game. Each of the relationships contains a property "GameID", which is used to identify the right relationship if you want to pass the graph via a path. So if you start traversing the graph at a node and follow the relationship with the right GameID, there won't be another path starting at the first node with a relationship that fits the GameID.
There are nodes that have hundreds of in and outgoing relationships, some others only have a few.

The problem is, that I don't know how to tell Cypher how to do this. The above query works for a depth of 1 or 2, but it should look like `[r:move*]` to return the whole path, which is about 20-200 hops.
But if i raise the values, the querys won't finish. I think that Cypher looks at each outgoing relationship at every single path depth relating to the start node, but as I already explained, there is only one right path. So it should do some kind of a DFS search instead of a BFS search. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider configuring a relationship index for the GameID property. See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html#auto-indexing-config.

Once you have done that, you can try a query like the following (I have not tested this):

```
START n=node(3), r=relationship:rels(GameID = 3)
MATCH (n)-[r*1..]->(m)
RETURN m;
```

Such a query would limit the relationships considered by the MATCH cause to just the ones with the GameID you care about. And getting that initial collection of relationships would be fast, because of the indexing.

As an aside: since neo4j reuses its internally-generated IDs (for nodes that are deleted), storing those IDs as GameIDs will make your data unreliable (unless you never delete any such nodes). You may want to generate and use you own unique IDs, and store them in your nodes and use them for your GameIDs; and, if you do this, then you should also create a uniqueness constraint for your own IDs -- this will, as a nice side effect, automatically create an index for your IDs.

Comment: Seems to be a good advice.
But since I don't use the Java API I can't setup a relationship index through that. Looks like Cypher can't do that.
I will give this one a try: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html#comment-567441858